# Escaping Shell Commands In java?

Tags: java, shell, escaping

I have a webservice that will take some input from authenticated machines as XML (this is for a network management system that I am integrating with some other software) and execute a shell script with some of the XML data as arguments.

In Java(/Linux), what is the best way to escape shell commands to ensure someone cannot pass malicious arguments to my webservice?

Basically in an extremely simplified example, Im taking some input in via WS

```
<foo>
<bar>ABCDEF</bar>
</foo>

then running somescript.pl <<data in <bar> field>> here
```

I need to ensure that this cannot be used to execute arbitrary shell commands,etc.

Thanks!

Comment: Which shell?  Different shells have different escaping conventions.

Comment: The question states Java on Linux.

Comment: @Gweebz, that doesn't answer the question "Which shell?". Linux has many different shells.

Comment: Fair question, I guess it doesnt even matter! I will investigate the ProcessBuilder and see if this will handle the data more safely. If I had to specify I guess I usually use bash in these cases!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I would suggest **using ProcessBuilder or one of the Runtime.exec methods *which does not* run through the shell** and thus *does not require shell escaping* to avoid injection attacks (here).

- [ProcessBuilder](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html) -- more flexible than `Runtime.exec`.
- [Runtime.exec(String[])](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec%28java.lang.String[]%29) -- differs from the form that takes only a `String`

It may also beneficial to consider using the process's STDIN pipe to transfer the XML data -- Perl can trivially handle reading from STDIN. There are generally limits with command-line arguments.

Happy coding.

Comment: Really a sensible answer. I would have written it the same, word by word, if you hadn't before. +1

Answer (score 3):

Patch supplied: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LANG-1066

That's really a long-standing issue.

Comment: This may be useful if the code executes a command interpreter explicitly with  ProcessBuilder and Runtime#exec.  The java documentation does not seem to stress the existing shell escape safety but other sources point out that no interpreter is invoked by Java implicitly.

Comment: Reading into [IDS07-J](https://wiki.sei.cmu.edu/confluence/display/java/IDS07-J.+Sanitize+untrusted+data+passed+to+the+Runtime.exec%28%29+method) and David Svoboda's comment, it appears that executing a string in POSIX by rt.exec() will fail if that string does not match a file name.  The array-argument prototype will translate directly to an array-argument POSIX exec() call which can turn bad when executing `sh` or other shells.  Using rt.exec() on Windows risks C runtime's parsing "solid" arguments into unexpected multiple ones but this depends on having `cmd` at the beginning of the string.

Answer (score 3):

If you can't use a ProcessBuilder you can consider [Apache commons-text `escapeXSI`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-text/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/text/StringEscapeUtils.html#escapeXSI-java.lang.String-).

(never mind the name - XSI is the X/Open System Interfaces Extension, a supplementary specification to the [Single UNIX Specification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_UNIX_Specification), so everything that tries to be UNIX-like more or less complies with this).

Comment: Thanks.  Using an older project, it took me a while to realize this was previously in `commons.lang3`, superseded by `commons.text`.  The `escapeXSI` is not part of the `commons.lang3` version, wanted to mention it for others. :)